# Стоит ли функцию как-либо называть или оставить анонимной?

Tags: javascript, функции, dom, prototype

Есть такой код:

```
if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {   // <----
    if (this.parentNode) {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
  };
}
```

Это обычный полифилл для .remove()

Меня интересует вопрос - есть ли какой-либо смысл называть как-то функцию вот тут:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function remove() { ... }
```

или в этом смысла нет, и можно её оставить анонимной?

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() { ... }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Имеет. При отладке эта функция будет выводиться в консоль в том виде, в каком она была в коде, поэтому в случае функции с именем будет сразу ясно, что это за функция. А ещё в ES6 вводится свойство name, которое в случае анонимной функции оказывается пустым.

```js
function Smth() {}

Smth.prototype.doSmth = function doSmth() {}
Smth.prototype.doOther = function () {}

var x = new Smth();

console.log(x.doSmth);
console.log(x.doOther);

console.log(x.doSmth.name);
console.log(x.doOther.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Никакого смысла не несёт. Только дублирвоание имени, на мой взгляд. Но, возможно, кому то нравится такой подход с явным именованием.

Comment: Не согласен. См в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Если в теле функции нет необходимости в доступе к самой себе, то смело можно использовать анонимный вариант наименования. Подробнее тут: [Именованные функциональные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/named-function-expression)

Comment: Не согласен. См в ответе. А именованные выражения - это несколько другое: то, что для рекурсии нужно имя, не означает, что без рекурсии имя не нужно.